# How to load static function (in C) from a dynamic library on Linux

Tags: c++, c, function, static

I have a static function "foo" in a dynamic library foolib. I am successfully able to load foolib in my application. Although dlsym returns NULL for "foo"

Even nm utility doesn't list static function as an exportable symbol.

I understand that static function has scope limited to that file.

Still, is there any way to achieve this.

I know this is possible in C++, don't know how and why (may be shared library is treated as object and functions within that library as interfaces.)

Answer (score 6):

`static` is not just a "scoping" thing - `static` functions have internal linkage, so no information about their existence is written by the compiler in the object file; such information cannot be recovered later (while creating the dynamic library).

Even better: if it's a small function it will probably be inlined in every circumstance, and, since it has internal linkage, there will be no need to generate the "standalone" version, so the function will actually not exist anymore after the compilation stage.

The only practical way I see to get an address to such a function "from the outside" would be to have another function in the same translation unit (i.e. in the same .cpp file) that returns a pointer to the `foo` function, and then export such helper function. Doable, but pretty pointless if you ask to me. :)

---

```
// In foolib

// The static function
static void foo()
{
    // ...
}

// Typedef for the function pointer
typedef void (* fooFuncPtr)();

// Helper function to be exported - returns the address of foo
fooFuncPtr fooHelper()
{
    return &foo;
}
```

---

```
typedef void (* fooFuncPtr)();
typedef fooFuncPtr (* fooHelperFuncPtr)();

// In the client code of foolib
// ...
fooHelperFuncPtr fooHelper = (fooHelperFuncPtr) dlsym(handle, "fooHelper");
// ... in real code here you would have error checking ...
fooFuncPtr foo = fooHelper();
// now you can use foo
foo();
```

Comment: so how this is accomplish in C++ ?

Comment: @Nile: edited answer. But, again, it's completely pointless, since while you are at it you can just remove `static` from that function instead of creating all this mess.

Comment: in C++ the meaning of `static` is changed if the function is a method of a class. It means its a class method as opposed to an object method. If using `static` on a normal funtion (outside of a class) I do not know if a C++ compiler will link it like the old C way

Comment: @Sodved: C++ gives yet another meaning to `static` when talking about member functions, but it keeps the same meaning as in C for free functions, although it was marked as deprecated in the C++98 standard in favor of anonymous namespaces (which I think were introduced to allow `static` member functions to have internal linkage). IIRC the pendulum has swung again, and now in C++11 it is no longer deprecated (see [basic.link] in the standard).